# Wordpress media upload error only on the screen add/edit post

Tags: wordpress

I've got a problem with uploading media on my wordpress website.
when I try to upload media files in the add new media page it works fine, but when I try it on the screen where we add/edit post. second screen is the error one.

I already checked the permission of directories and also turned all plug ins off and tried it.

could any one help me out ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a permission issue, Can you please try to set permission on wp-content folder as well as upload folder?

For reference: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-image-upload-issue-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it was permission issue. some of folders in uploads folder was owned by root. I changed it as 82. and it works fine now.